# Retrieving alias of a property from a Model with ORMLite and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ormlite-servicestack

I have the following class:

```
[Schema("dbo")]
[Alias("accesses")]
public class Acces{
    [Alias("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Alias("device_id")]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    [Alias("client_id")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Alias("person_uid")]
    public string PersonUid { get; set; }

}
```

How can I programmatically retrieve, for example, the `ORMLite` `Alias` for `PersonUid`?

I tried using `typeof(Access).GetModelMetadata()` (dumping it too), but with no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a helper for this on my project. Hope this helps!

```
public static class OrmLiteExtensions
{
    public static string GetQuotedName<T>(string propertyName, bool appendTablePrefix = true)
    {
        var sqlFieldName = string.Empty;
        var modelDefinition = typeof(T).GetModelMetadata();
        if (appendTablePrefix)
            sqlFieldName = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.GetQuotedName(modelDefinition.ModelName) + ".";
        sqlFieldName += modelDefinition.FieldDefinitions.First(p => p.Name == propertyName).GetQuotedName(OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider);
        return sqlFieldName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
OrmLiteExtensions.GetQuotedName<Acces>(nameof(Acces.DeviceId), false); // pass true in second parameter to prefix with table name
```